# Buscar outros resultados do select

Tags: php, html, html-select

Bom dia galera!

Tenho um código onde eu busco os cadastros pela cidade. Código abaixo:

```
<form name="frmBusca" method="post" class="w3-container w3-center w3-row-padding" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>?a=buscar">

<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Nome:</h4><input type="texto" class="" name="nome" placeholder="Nome"/></div>
<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Função:</h4><input type="texto" name="cargo_pretendido"  placeholder="Ex: Motorista"/></div>
<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Cidade:</h4>
        <select type="checkbox" class="w3-center w3-bordered" style="width:207px;" name="cidade">
                <option value="%%%%">TODOS</option>
                <option value="camboriu">Camboriú</option>
                <option value="balneario camboriu">Balneário Camboriú</option>
                <option value="itapema">Itapema</option>
                <option value="porto">Porto Belo</option>
                <option value="itajai">Itajaí</option>
        </select></div>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php

if ($a == "buscar") {

$id = trim($_POST['id']);
$nome = trim($_POST['nome']);
$endereco = trim($_POST['endereco']);
$numero = trim($_POST['numero']);
$cidade = trim($_POST['cidade']);
$bairro = trim($_POST['bairro']);
$telefone = trim($_POST['telefone']);
$celular = trim($_POST['celular']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$data_nascimento = trim($_POST['data_nascimento']);
$estado_civil = trim($_POST['estado_civil']);
$habilitado = trim($_POST['habilitado']);
$n_registro = trim($_POST['n_registro']);
$categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
$cpf = trim($_POST['cpf']);
$rg = trim($_POST['rg']);
$cargo_pretendido = trim($_POST['cargo_pretendido']);
$nivel_hierarquico = trim($_POST['nivel_hierarquico']);
$area_atuacao = trim($_POST['area_atuacao']);
$grau_instrucao = trim($_POST['grau_instrucao']);
$tecnico_data = trim($_POST['tecnico_data']);
$superior_data = trim($_POST['superior_data']);
$empresa1 = trim($_POST['empresa1']);
$cargoempresa1 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa1']);
$dt_admissao1 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao1']);
$dt_demissao1 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao1']);
$empresa2 = trim($_POST['empresa2']);
$cargoempresa2 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa2']);
$dt_admissao2 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao2']);
$dt_demissao2 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao2']);
$empresa3 = trim($_POST['empresa3']);
$cargoempresa3 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa3']);
$dt_admissao3 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao3']);
$dt_demissao3 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao3']);
$observacoes = trim($_POST['observacoes']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pr_curriculo WHERE id LIKE '%".$id."%' AND nome LIKE '%".$nome."%' AND endereco LIKE '%".$endereco."%' AND numero LIKE '%".$numero."%' AND cidade LIKE '".$cidade."%' AND bairro LIKE '%".$bairro."%' AND telefone LIKE '%".$telefone."%' AND celular LIKE '%".$celular."%' AND email LIKE '%".$email."%' AND data_nascimento LIKE '%".$data_nascimento."%' AND estado_civil LIKE '%".$estado_civil."%' AND habilitado LIKE '%".$habilitado."%' AND n_registro LIKE '%".$n_registro."%' AND categoria LIKE '%".$categoria."%' AND cpf LIKE '%".$cpf."%' AND rg LIKE '%".$rg."%' AND cargo_pretendido LIKE '%".$cargo_pretendido."%' AND nivel_hierarquico LIKE '%".$nivel_hierarquico."%' AND area_atuacao LIKE '%".$area_atuacao."%' AND grau_instrucao LIKE '%".$grau_instrucao."%' AND tecnico_data LIKE '%".$tecnico_data."%' AND superior_data LIKE '%".$superior_data."%' AND empresa1 LIKE '%".$empresa1."%' AND cargoempresa1 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa1."%' AND dt_admissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao1."%' AND dt_demissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao1."%' AND empresa2 LIKE '%".$empresa2."%' AND cargoempresa2 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa2."%' AND dt_admissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao2."%' AND dt_demissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao2."%' AND empresa3 LIKE '%".$empresa3."%' AND cargoempresa3 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa3."%' AND dt_admissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao3."%' AND dt_demissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao3."%' AND curso LIKE '%".$curso."%' AND observacoes LIKE '%".$observacoes."%'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); 
    $qt_linhas= mysqli_num_rows($query);

    ?>
```

Quero ter um option que busque todos os resultados exceto os acima, como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que os outros resultados são diversas cidades, não só duas ou três...

Comment: Poste o javascript que estás a fazer a requisição para o back-end. Mas isso não da para limitar direto no `SELECT` do banco utilizando um `NOT IN`, por exemplo ?

Comment: Eu tenho um $sql que busca todas as informações no banco. Quando fosse o option outros eu teria que ter um $sql2 que buscasse tudo exceto aquelas cidades acima?

Comment: Meu sql está assim... $sql = "SELECT * FROM pr_curriculo WHERE id LIKE '%".$id."%' AND nome LIKE '%".$nome."%' AND endereco LIKE '%".$endereco."%' AND numero LIKE '%".$numero."%' AND cidade LIKE '".$cidade."%'

Comment: Como quer buscar vários valores, recomendo usar o `IN` invés do `like`.

Comment: Não entendi... Quero buscar um valor por vez. Uma consulta "porto belo", uma consulta "itapema", uma consulta "outros"..

Comment: Certo, então na opção "outros" não buscará as options listadas? "Camboriu", "Itapema", etc? São só essas opções?

Comment: Isso, outros busca tudo exceto as já citadas.

Comment: Certo. Poste o seu arquivo `PHP` que recebe esses dados para eu criar um exemplo.

Comment: http://dontpad.com/phpstackoverflow Aqui está o código, é meio grande. Se precisar de alguma outra parte do código só pedir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisará identificar qual o `valor` está sendo capturado na variável `$cidade` para então tomar a ação.

A lógica é bem simples: Caso o valor for igual a  `OUTROS`, o `select` será montado negando as cidades que você não deseja trazer, caso o valor for diferente de `OUTROS`, irá pesquisar pela cidade que for postada.

O seu código ficará assim:

```
  <?php

if ($a == "buscar") {

$id = trim($_POST['id']);
$nome = trim($_POST['nome']);
$endereco = trim($_POST['endereco']);
$numero = trim($_POST['numero']);
$cidade = trim($_POST['cidade']);
$bairro = trim($_POST['bairro']);
$telefone = trim($_POST['telefone']);
$celular = trim($_POST['celular']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$data_nascimento = trim($_POST['data_nascimento']);
$estado_civil = trim($_POST['estado_civil']);
$habilitado = trim($_POST['habilitado']);
$n_registro = trim($_POST['n_registro']);
$categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
$cpf = trim($_POST['cpf']);
$rg = trim($_POST['rg']);
$cargo_pretendido = trim($_POST['cargo_pretendido']);
$nivel_hierarquico = trim($_POST['nivel_hierarquico']);
$area_atuacao = trim($_POST['area_atuacao']);
$grau_instrucao = trim($_POST['grau_instrucao']);
$tecnico_data = trim($_POST['tecnico_data']);
$superior_data = trim($_POST['superior_data']);
$empresa1 = trim($_POST['empresa1']);
$cargoempresa1 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa1']);
$dt_admissao1 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao1']);
$dt_demissao1 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao1']);
$empresa2 = trim($_POST['empresa2']);
$cargoempresa2 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa2']);
$dt_admissao2 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao2']);
$dt_demissao2 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao2']);
$empresa3 = trim($_POST['empresa3']);
$cargoempresa3 = trim($_POST['cargoempresa3']);
$dt_admissao3 = trim($_POST['dt_admissao3']);
$dt_demissao3 = trim($_POST['dt_demissao3']);
$observacoes = trim($_POST['observacoes']);

if($cidade == "OUTROS") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pr_curriculo WHERE id LIKE '%".$id."%' AND nome LIKE '%".$nome."%' AND endereco LIKE '%".$endereco."%' AND numero LIKE '%".$numero."%' AND cidade NOT IN ('cidade1', 'cidade2', 'cidade3' etc...) AND bairro LIKE '%".$bairro."%' AND telefone LIKE '%".$telefone."%' AND celular LIKE '%".$celular."%' AND email LIKE '%".$email."%' AND data_nascimento LIKE '%".$data_nascimento."%' AND estado_civil LIKE '%".$estado_civil."%' AND habilitado LIKE '%".$habilitado."%' AND n_registro LIKE '%".$n_registro."%' AND categoria LIKE '%".$categoria."%' AND cpf LIKE '%".$cpf."%' AND rg LIKE '%".$rg."%' AND cargo_pretendido LIKE '%".$cargo_pretendido."%' AND nivel_hierarquico LIKE '%".$nivel_hierarquico."%' AND area_atuacao LIKE '%".$area_atuacao."%' AND grau_instrucao LIKE '%".$grau_instrucao."%' AND tecnico_data LIKE '%".$tecnico_data."%' AND superior_data LIKE '%".$superior_data."%' AND empresa1 LIKE '%".$empresa1."%' AND cargoempresa1 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa1."%' AND dt_admissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao1."%' AND dt_demissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao1."%' AND empresa2 LIKE '%".$empresa2."%' AND cargoempresa2 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa2."%' AND dt_admissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao2."%' AND dt_demissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao2."%' AND empresa3 LIKE '%".$empresa3."%' AND cargoempresa3 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa3."%' AND dt_admissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao3."%' AND dt_demissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao3."%' AND curso LIKE '%".$curso."%' AND observacoes LIKE '%".$observacoes."%'";
}

else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pr_curriculo WHERE id LIKE '%".$id."%' AND nome LIKE '%".$nome."%' AND endereco LIKE '%".$endereco."%' AND numero LIKE '%".$numero."%' AND cidade LIKE '".$cidade."%' AND bairro LIKE '%".$bairro."%' AND telefone LIKE '%".$telefone."%' AND celular LIKE '%".$celular."%' AND email LIKE '%".$email."%' AND data_nascimento LIKE '%".$data_nascimento."%' AND estado_civil LIKE '%".$estado_civil."%' AND habilitado LIKE '%".$habilitado."%' AND n_registro LIKE '%".$n_registro."%' AND categoria LIKE '%".$categoria."%' AND cpf LIKE '%".$cpf."%' AND rg LIKE '%".$rg."%' AND cargo_pretendido LIKE '%".$cargo_pretendido."%' AND nivel_hierarquico LIKE '%".$nivel_hierarquico."%' AND area_atuacao LIKE '%".$area_atuacao."%' AND grau_instrucao LIKE '%".$grau_instrucao."%' AND tecnico_data LIKE '%".$tecnico_data."%' AND superior_data LIKE '%".$superior_data."%' AND empresa1 LIKE '%".$empresa1."%' AND cargoempresa1 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa1."%' AND dt_admissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao1."%' AND dt_demissao1 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao1."%' AND empresa2 LIKE '%".$empresa2."%' AND cargoempresa2 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa2."%' AND dt_admissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao2."%' AND dt_demissao2 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao2."%' AND empresa3 LIKE '%".$empresa3."%' AND cargoempresa3 LIKE '%".$cargoempresa3."%' AND dt_admissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_admissao3."%' AND dt_demissao3 LIKE '%".$dt_demissao3."%' AND curso LIKE '%".$curso."%' AND observacoes LIKE '%".$observacoes."%'";
}

    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); 
    $qt_linhas= mysqli_num_rows($query);

    ?>
```

**Observações:**

No seu formulário:

```
<

form name="frmBusca" method="post" class="w3-container w3-center w3-row-padding" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>?a=buscar">

<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Nome:</h4><input type="texto" class="" name="nome" placeholder="Nome"/></div>
<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Função:</h4><input type="texto" name="cargo_pretendido"  placeholder="Ex: Motorista"/></div>
<div class="w3-section"><h4 class="w3-text-black">Cidade:</h4>
        <select type="checkbox" class="w3-center w3-bordered" style="width:207px;" name="cidade">
                <option value="OUTROS">TODOS</option>
                <option value="camboriu">Camboriú</option>
                <option value="balneario camboriu">Balneário Camboriú</option>
                <option value="itapema">Itapema</option>
                <option value="porto">Porto Belo</option>
                <option value="itajai">Itajaí</option>
        </select></div>
```

No código PHP, lembre-se de colocar as cidades que não serão inclusas no select dentro do `if`.

Comment: Resolvido meu problema! Só tive alguns empecilhos com gente escrevendo "itajai sc" ao invés de itajaí, mas nada que não dê para contornar. Muito obrigado pela sua resolução!

Comment: @MickaelRocha que bom poder ajudar!